# Splitting a SQL Server column without cutting word in half

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on this and hoping someone has something that could help. I have a table called `ITEMS` with 2 columns, `ITEMNO` and `DESCRIPT`

The `DESCRIPT` column is 40 characters long. I need to write a query that will split this into to columns, with a max of 30 characters. However I can not cut a word in half.

I have tried all kinds of methods but can not get anything to work. So if a `DESCRIPT` column has 37 characters total, and 30 there is a character and not a white space, I need to go backwards to find whitespace. This will part will become the first NEW description column and what ever was left after that point, will be the second new description column

Comment: google and learn about CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING() in sql server.

Comment: Google was the first place i looked. Here is what i came up with, but in the end it was still causing words to be cut off, hence why i am asking for help. This may get a little confusing, because i am also replacing certain words from the field with blank spaces.

Comment: Substring(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(i.descript,';',''),'assyparts',''),'DC',''), 0 , 28 + 2 - CharIndex(' ',  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(i.descript,';',''),'assyparts',''),'DC',''), 0, 28 + 1 )),0)),';',
  replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(i.descript,';',''),'assyparts',''),'DC',''),Substring(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(i.descript,';',''),'assyparts',''),'DC',''), 0 , 28 + 2 - CharIndex(' ',  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(i.descript,';',''),'assyparts',''),'DC',''), 0, 28 + 1 )),0)),''),';',

Comment: Did your code get truncated?   It shouldn't work ending with a comma like you have it posted.

Comment: The comma is there because its a copy and paste from the full query.

Comment: The easiest way to find last space is to reverse the string and look the first one with charindex.

Comment: and the ';' sitting there before the comma with no closing parenthesis?

Comment: JamesZ- I am reversing (however i could not be using it correctly)
Tab- also for business purposes. The export should show for example description1, description2, ; , some field, ; , some field, ;  etc etc

Comment: What if there is no white space at all? Are any other delimiters allowed (such as ,.;- etc')?

Comment: No nothing else. Its a big mess as to what is in that field. There will for sure be  a white space though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ITEMNO,
       DESCRIPT,
       CASE WHEN LEN(DESCRIPT) > 30
       THEN
         LEFT(DESCRIPT, 30 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(DESCRIPT, 30))))
       ELSE
         DESCRIPT
       END As Descript1,

       CASE WHEN LEN(DESCRIPT) > 30
       THEN
         RIGHT(DESCRIPT, LEN(DESCRIPT) - (30 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(DESCRIPT, 30)))))
       ELSE
         NULL
       END As Descript2
FROM ITEMS
```

Explanation:

The first case is to return the entire text of the column if it's less then 30 chars, or calculate the length untill the first whitespace:
`LEFT(descript,30)` will return the first 30 chars.
`CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(DESCRIPT, 30)))` reverse this string and look for the first whitespace, 
`LEFT(DESCRIPT, 30 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(DESCRIPT, 30))))` cuts the original string on the last whitespace before the 31th char.

The other column is really just the same, only use RIGHT and len(descript) - the position of the last whitespace before the 30th char.

The second case is there to avoid exceptions if the column's text is less then 30 chars.

[see sql fiddle here (updated)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77cbff/2)

Comment: Zohar, 
This is close but not working. Here is an example of the output
#1/4/9-BOX | 15 1/2 x 4 1/4 x 50 Box ECT |15 1/2 x 4 1/4 x 50 Box EC

Notice it cut the "T" off of ECT. I put pipes in the separate, here is untouched copy and paste 
#1/4/9-BOX 15 1/2 x 4 1/4 x 50 Box ECT 15 1/2 x 4 1/4 x 50 Box EC

Comment: Please use the link to the sql fiddle I've posted to update some sample data and add it in a link in the comments. It's very hard to undestand the problem from the comments like this.

Comment: I sow the problem and fixed it. see my edited answer.